# Правильный шаблон для регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

**z_abcd0123.jpg** - имя картинки

Нужен шаблон проверки для **preg_match()**

Условия:

**где z** - символы a-z длинной 1 символ,

**где abcd0123** - символы a-f, 0-9 длинной 8 символов,

**jpg** - символы a-z длинной до 5 символов

Наработки, естественно, не работают:

```
preg_match("[a-z]{1}\_[a-f0-9]{8}\.[a-z]{,5}",$img)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы были очень близки)

```
preg_match("/[a-z]{1}\_[a-f0-9]{8}\.[a-z]{3,5}/", $img);
```

Можно еще `$img` через `strtolower` прогонять.

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-z]{1}\_[a-f0-9]{8}\.[a-z]{3,5}
```

P.S. вконтактик?

Comment: почти...просто по такому же механизму буду давать имена картинкам

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем просто ( быстро, но не так избирательно ), то:

```
/\w{10}\.\w{,5}/ или /\w{10}\.\w{0,5}/
```

Если-же добавить условия:

```
/[a-z]\_[a-f\d]{8}\.[a-z]{,5}/ или /[a-z]\_[a-f\d]{8}\.[a-z]{0,5}/
```

НО:

1. Расширение файла может содержать цифры - хотя-бы тот-же `mp3`
2. Файл может быть без расширения

Поэтому ИМХО: Решайте конкретную задачу! Насколько я понимаю - фотография из контакта:

```
/[a-z]\_[a-z\d]{8}\.jpg/
```

Comment: Вопрос поставлен - ответ есть, и он меня устраивает

1. Я не знаю картинок с расширением mp3
2. Файл не может быть без расширения, ибо при загрузке файла ему даётся случайное имя **и** в конце, расширение

Comment: `JPEG-2000` имеет расширение `.jp2`

Comment: Ну это какие то заоблачные форматы, которые в условиях вопроса не фигурировали, а значит мне и не нужны.
Но спасибо, погуглил